# How can i Go back to line 1 if condition is false Python

Tags: python

**How can i go back to Line 1 if Condition is false.**

```
while True:
    food = int(input("food bill: "))
    if food <= 10:
        print("please write more than 10")
#If i put break statement here it does not go forward
    else:
        carbill = int(input("carbill: "))
    print("Total Montlhy expenditure is : " , grandtotal)
```

Comment: I think you want `continue`?

Comment: Use a `continue`.

Comment: In continue it does not go forward even i increase the value e.g when i put 20 it return to food bill again.

Comment: @AsimKhan Make sure your indentation is correct.

Comment: Anton vBR  Thanks for the comments. Now it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want-

```
while True:
    food = int(input("food bill: "))
    if food <= 10:
       print("please write more than 10")
       continue
    carbill = int(input("carbill: "))
    print("Total Montlhy expenditure is : " , food+carbill)
```

Comment: No need for an else-clause though.

Comment: @AntonvBR correct. Haste makes such a waste. Edited.

Comment: @AntonvBR jeez, i am so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `continue`, it will go back to the loop instruction (works for `for` well).